# Secondary Capture Image: what is the correct workflow for creating and storing?

Tags: dicom, imaging, medical

I need to create a **Secondary Capture Image** representing a report related to radiopharmaceutical and dose  injected to the patient during the medical examination.
I know  Secondary Capture Image  is not the right choice to accomplish the task but that is  what the customer requires.

Following are the steps I thought to implement for  developing  the feature  and I would  like to read some opinions  or suggestion from the community.

Assumption: MWL is implemented and  the Study Instance UID is generated in the RIS

1. query the MWL (C-FIND) to get the requested procedure object
2. parse the result to get the StudyInstanceUID and patient related
   informations (name, sex, birthdate  etc.)
3. query (C –FIND)  the modality looking for the specific  Study
   Instance UID
4. parse the result to get the Series Instance UID
5. create the image  setting the  three mandatory attribute  Study
   Instance UID, Series Instance UID, Modality (together with some type
   2 attributes I got querying   MWL and modality in the previous
   steps)
6. C-STORE to persist the image to the storage archive
7. Commit  of the image (do I really need?)

I really appreciate comments  opinions or someone that can address me to a more  solid architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. correct
2. correct. Do not forget about attributes that are not so obvious like Admission ID, Accession Number, Referring Physicians Name and others.
3. The majority of modalities does not support Query/Retrieve as an SCP. If you would really need to query for the images, send the C-FIND to the PACS rather than the modality. The Study Instance UID comes with the worklist. Even if the UID you find by Query differs from that, I would strongly recommend to use the one from the worklist. However, I do not see any sense in using attributes from other sources than the MWL and your own "acquisition".
4. Why would you want to add the image to an existing series? It would probably be more appropriate to create a new one. There are a lot of reasons for that, e.g. Modality and vendor/equipment information are series level information and probably different.
5. There are more mandatory attributes for SC (e.g. in the general image module). Not all come from the MWL.
6. yes.
7. You do not have to. However, suppose that your images are lost:

   a) you have received a storage commitment from the PACS -> blame on the PACS

   b) you have not received a storage commitment from the PACS -> blame on ...? ;-)